# Hosting API docs generated with mkdocs at a URL within a Django project

Tags: python, django, mkdocs

I tend to write my API documentation in Markdown and generate a static site with MkDocs.  However, the site I'd like to host the documentation on is a Django site.  So my question is, and I can't seem to find an answer Googling around, is how would I go about hosting the MkDocs static generated site files at a location like `/api/v1/docs` and have the static site viewable at that URL?

**UPDATE:**
I should point out I do serve all static files under Apache and do NOT use runserver or Debug mode to serve static files, that's just crazy. The site is completely built and working along with a REST API.

My question was simply how do I get Django (or should I say Apache) to serve the static site (for my API docs) generated by MkDocs under a certain URL. I understand how to serve media and static files for the site, but not necessarily how to serve what MkDocs generates.  It generates a completely static 'site' directory with HTML and assets files in it.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I figured it out.  While I always serve my static (media and static) files with Apache during production,when I develop I use `runserver`. Joran's Comment pointed me in the right direction to get the site files generated by MkDocs to serve up at a URL while I'm developing (in Debug mode).  I added the directory the MkDocs are in to my vhost and all is well when I run it using Apache (and `Debug = False` of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive in apache and use that to redirect certain URLs to your static documentation site.

Comment: Yea, this is what I finally figured out (I'm an idiot), to stop thinking of it as Django serving the generated docs part of the site at a specific URL vs in reality (when in production) Apache will serve the directory of the static site at the URL.

Answer (score 4):

Django is just a framework you need to host your static files and serve them with something like Nginx or Apache etc.

Comment: True, but if the OP wants to use static files in production best practices suggest above.

Comment: i concure I was just about to type that ... but who knows how he is serving his site (apache probably :( , or maybe runserver)

Answer (score 0):

from the docs

```
urls = [
    static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT),
    ("/home","views.home"),
    ...

 ]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

in your request you would change to

```
 static("/api/v0/docs",document_root="/home/docs/")
```

Comment: I would note here that "This is not suitable for production use" as stated in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: yeah good point ... your suggestion is correct in that he should serve static files via apache or nginx